# Monitor incoming IP connections in Amazon AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I am using Amazon RDS and I want to know which IP addresses are connecting to my database. My security groups are set to none, and my connection is set to public, I CANT SET IT TO PRIVATE AND SPECIFY AN IP, thats not what im looking for. I just want to know if there is a way to see who is connecting to my database server.
Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use VPC flow logs to get the information you are looking for. Refer [this document](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/flow-logs.html) on VPC flow logs that explain what it is.